# Docker: User upload image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a local web app running with docker (php, apache and mySQL) and all is fine on local environment. I deployed to Digital Ocean, mySQL is running and html is ok as well EXCEPT show user uploaded image files.

I have a Admin system, where the user can upload product images, the files are being save in the "asset" folder. There's isn't any error on chrome dev tools and no errors on Digital Ocean logs too. The files is being uploaded, but I can't access them to show to my user!

How to do it?

[image]

Best

[image]

Comment: post screenshot of the website with chrome dev showing the image location ?

Comment: Hello Ganesh! Thanks!!  Adding the image to the post!

Comment: as per script asset folder seems to be one level up.. hope thats how its in your docker container too.. also does entire path  have read access to all users ?

Comment: I tried a lot of paths on chrome dev tools...what path do you suggest? I don't know how to link a docker volume to the asset folder...I think this is the problem...what you think?

Comment: did you try login to container to see the images ? 

docker exec -it <containername> bash

Comment: yes! actually, just saw that the images aren't being uploaded...all these images are from my local server...